# Calculate in recursive manner in Snowflake

Tags: sql, recursion, math, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hT1f.png)

```
| Quarter | Price | Percent | ID  | Output 
|:----     |:------:| -----:|---: |-----:
| Q218     | 10     | 0.00   | 1  |10
| Q318     | 10     | 0.05   | 1  |9.5(10-(10*0.05))
| Q418     | 10     | 0.06   | 1  |8.93(9.5-(10*0.06))
| Q119     | 10     | 0.05   | 1  |8.48(8.93-(10*0.06))
```

I want the price to recursively take the ID subtract percent from Price recursively using the output of previous line.

Trying to find the output column in a recursive method in Snowflake.
What should be right function to use in snowflake.

I have tried windowing function but looking for any better approach to deal efficiently.

Comment: Please could you edit your question and add simple data and the expected output as text not image, so it can be easy for us to help

Comment: Also could you add what you have tried ?

Comment: Can you check now if this works .Let me know if I have to re-indent it again.

Comment: Are the values in the Percent column actual values rather than percentages (I.e. they are not 0.2%)? If they are then just use a Windows function in a CTE to get a row number for each record within each group and then in the main query calculate Price - (Percent * Row Number)

Comment: I have reframed for better understanding.Input to my 2nd row would be the O/p of 1st row.Thank you